Decode GCP Oauth Bearer Token
I am trying to debug an permission issue and trying to find out what is inside oauth bearer token which is used to call pubsub apis.
I have got bearer token with me by enabling logging.

{"timestampSeconds":1712307807,"timestampNanos":830000000,"severity":"INFO","thread":"Gax-14","logger":"com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport","message":"{"access_token":"ya29.d.c0AY_VpZj3evneMQ8dN3nvslVcq86RiIpMT4dOYB3_KxQ7xxZzoiRemCC28bhXuGxZhD1maF7Q49rXXXXXXXXXFiaEh9EtNbqvjEFqYT79vzKKenAltm2HA80_TM2Oc4BB7DECjh9sgVD6bF-Xwk7IbQv8N8XXXXXXXld1XDjPkEyYhcyCNzklSmAQS0WP-K8wceLgHTdkPzQTKEUHAFpVr6B797rUrSRHBqlok-XEK1xxTqP-YgRKD_YYClJRvynq3pL7XXTlin7t_kzVu5JCawS6SSAtGaPow3KUjYTJrKJyPnxGQP7_76hUzmm5MbAaG-jhX7jVREckgzWZSAytGqQll1m1tSnwG2qnNOWI_Orj3MmoKP0c5_Uke1faJxI2YnI6DKNz8NItuXAXkWehabve94Uk_3yU4WXg9GEAJXXXXXXXXXX_s0bOxRCAa5pVh450ojTD1LKre1Mi3dyi33fp_Q9YAAb2Amdu7kOuu_Nyib4ky3vqZ2hiubE4PRvu9AN4buaEqAjjeJOGKn55O_bTggNU8nPhqNRLs","expires_in":3598,"token_type":"Bearer"}","context":"default"}

Publish Request

{"timestampSeconds":1712307913,"timestampNanos":796000000,"severity":"DEBUG","thread":"grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-1","logger":"io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler","message":"[id:
0xe0a011e9, L:/10.70.5.54:37214 -
R:pubsub.googleapis.com/108.177.15.95:443] OUTBOUND HEADERS:
streamId\u003d9 headers\u003dGrpcHttp2OutboundHeaders[:authority:
pubsub.googleapis.com:443, :path: /google.pubsub.v1.Publisher/Publish,
:method: POST, :scheme: https, content-type: application/grpc, te:
trailers, user-agent: grpc-java-netty/1.39.0, x-goog-api-client:
gl-java/17.0.4 gapic/1.113.5 gax/1.66.0 grpc/1.39.0,
x-goog-request-params:
topic\u003dprojects/testing-development/topics/testing-bacd-testing-1,
grpc-accept-encoding: gzip, authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXX,
grpc-timeout: 4999700u] streamDependency\u003d0 weight\u003d16
exclusive\u003dfalse padding\u003d0
endStream\u003dfalse","context":"default"}

Attempts
I tried this but didn't work.
$TOKEN contains access_token from response.
curl -i "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?access_token=$TOKEN"
HTTP/2 400 
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
date: Fri, 05 Apr 2024 09:06:40 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
vary: X-Origin
vary: Referer
vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
server: ESF
x-xss-protection: 0
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
accept-ranges: none

{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}

How can i decode this token ?

Put only the access_token which starts with ya29 and not the whole JSON

Thanks and yes I've put the access_token only.

Which endpoint did you use to generate the token? There are several tokeninfo endpoints. I use this one: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo

Work like a charm for me! curl -i "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?access_token=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"

@guillaumeblaquiere, My token was coming by service account's credentials than a gcp user and you might have used your user account's access-token which worked for as well.

@JohnHanley My Java program uses spring gcp pubsub library and there I created and used a service account so access_token is created on the fly.

I do not see those details in your question. Since your issue is an invalid token, show how you are obtaining a token.

Check https://jpassing.com/2023/01/24/all-google-access-tokens-are-not-created-equal/, it says the tokeninfo does not work for STS tokens (aka starting with ya29.d)
